# CSS Height update after page size increase

Tags: css

I am creating an application that has a menu on the left hand side of the screen. The menu has the following CSS applied to it:

```
.menu .levelHolderClass {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    background: #336ca6;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

This works until the screen dynamically resizes to show more contents as the screen is a table-like structure loading content as the user scrolls down.

Is there any particular CSS tag which I can use to indicate that the element should resize after the page size has increased? Currently when the screen adds more rows the menu stops after 100% screen height.

If there is no CSS tag to do this, how would you approach it in Javascript?

**Edit:** The images below shows the menu (blue bar) before and after scrolling down past 1 page height.

[image: Menu before scrolling] [image: Menu after scrolling]

Comment: Could you try reproduce the issue here? You can create embedded html/css/js here.

Comment: I'm extending quite a large app that already exists. Replicating in JSFiddle would be quite time consuming. I've added two images to help with the explanation.

Comment: add `height: 1vh;` to `.menu .levelHolderClass` and try

Comment: `height: 1vh;` did not work.

Comment: sorry it is 100vh and is partially supported in IE 11

Comment: I did try that too, it did not work either sorry.

Comment: cant you add `bottom, : 0;` as well & and what is the code for the parent element

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily appease the issue, I've added :

```
position: fixed;
```

to the css. This makes the menu at least scroll with the user regardless of the page resizing.